# Get attachments hyperlink from a list

Tags: 2013, jquery, attachments

I have a SharePoint 2013 list TestList. Each record of my list has three attachments... I am trying to get the links of each attachment and display it in a table using jQuery. Is it possible?

My code:

```
var id;
$().SPServices({

        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName:"Test",
            webURL:"http://sharepoint.pfizer.com/sites/test/",
        CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/></ViewFields>',
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
        {
         $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() 
                    {
                    id=parseInt($(this).attr("ows_ID"));
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebProperties, "SP.js"); 
var attachmentFiles;
function getWebProperties() {
var itemId=id;
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var attachmentFolder=web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/Test/Attachments/'+itemId);
attachmentFiles= attachmentFolder.get_files();
ctx.load(attachmentFiles);              
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this,this.onFailed));
}
function onSuccess(sender, args) {                                
var i=0;
for(var file in attachmentFiles) {                              
    alert(attachmentFiles.itemAt(i).get_serverRelativeUrl());
    i++;
}
}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
alert("Not found!");

}
});
}
});
```

Comment: am getting an error " Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below REST API endpoint:

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

The full code would be somewhat as below using REST API:

```
$.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.results.length>0){
                    for(var i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)
                    {
                        var item = data.d.results[i];
                        var attachments = item.AttachmentFiles;
                        if(attachments!=null){
                            for(var j=0;j<attachments.length;j++)
                            {
                                var attachUrl = attachments[j].ServerRelativeUrl;
                                console.log(attachUrl); //this is your attachment url
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }               
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
      });
```

**Edited** -  Since you are using SPServices, you can also try below code:

```
var id;
$().SPServices({

        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName:"Test",
        webURL:"http://sharepoint.pfizer.com/sites/test/",
        CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><FieldRef Name=\'Attachments\'/></ViewFields>',
        CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><IncludeAttachmentUrls>TRUE</IncludeAttachmentUrls></QueryOptions>",
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
        {
         $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() 
                {
                    id=parseInt($(this).attr("ows_ID"));
                    var attachments = [];  
                    var attCollection = $(this).attr("ows_Attachments");
                    if(attCollection !== "0") {
                        attachments = attCollection.split(";#"); // Now you'll have an array of attachment URLs
                        //iterate over this array
                        for(var j=0;j<attachments.length;j++)
                        {
                            var url = attachments[j];//untested, check the values here
                        }

                    } else {
                        // attCollection will be "0", indicating that there are no attachments
                    }

                });
        }
});
```

References - [Get attachments using SPservices 2013](https://deversoy.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/get-attachments-using-spservices-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[SPXmltoJSON](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/utilities/SPXmlToJson.html)

Comment: OKay...Will check and let you know

Comment: But a small change...need to add Attachments in ViewFields :p

Comment: Hi, this worked perfectly fine..but I am trying to pass the url dynamically in the anchor tag..And if the url has spaces or special characters..the url is breaking up..

Comment: you can try it as `var url = encodeURIComponent(attachments[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebProperties, "SP.js"); 
var attachmentFiles;
function getWebProperties() {
var itemId=2;
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var attachmentFolder=web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/City/Attachments/'+itemId);
attachmentFiles= attachmentFolder.get_files();
ctx.load(attachmentFiles);              
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this,this.onFailed));
}
function onSuccess(sender, args) {                                
var i=0;
for(var file in attachmentFiles) {                              
    alert(attachmentFiles.itemAt(i).get_serverRelativeUrl());
    i++;
}
}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
alert("sorry!");

}
```

Comment: Am able to  retrieve only one record attachments links using this...When I dynamically tried to pass the itemId..It is throwing me an error "Unable to get property 'get_serverRelativeUrl' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Basically I want to iterate through all the records each time using SPServices each function

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I've used in the past to show links to all attachments for a list item - this was showing attachments on a PO page.

```
<div id="fmgAttach" class="fmgNoPrint"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/JQuery/JQueryMin-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Javascript/JQuery/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var attachments = '';

// here, get the id for the list item from query parameters or other code. Change the red code to use your ID variable.


    attachments += retrieveAttachments($(this).attr("ows_ID"));

// after you've retrieve the attachments, attach the html to division

 $('#fmgAttach').append(attachments);


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Function - Retrieve Attachments with Edit
// ------------------------------------------------------------

function retrieveAttachments(poID) {
var outputTitle = "<span class='fmgSectionH1'>Attachments for PO</span><br /><br />You can read and edit from these links. Attach via the 'Edit PO Header' button -> Attach File in the ribbon. Remember to click Save when done.<br /><br />";
var output = "";
var outputlinks = "";
 var found = false;
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetAttachmentCollection",
  listName: "Purchase Orders",
  ID: poID,
  async: false,
  completefunc: function( xData, Status ) {

   $( xData.responseXML ).find("Attachments > Attachment").each(function( i, el ) {
   found = true;
    var $node = $(this),
     filePath = $node.text(),
     arrString = filePath.split("/"),
     fileName = arrString[ arrString.length - 1 ]
    ;
      outputlinks += "<a href='" + filePath + "' target='_blank' onclick=\"DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '1', '');return false;\" >"; 
    outputlinks += fileName;
    outputlinks += "</a><br /><br />";

   });

  }
 });


 return (outputTitle + "<table width='100%'><tr><td>" + outputlinks + "</td><td>" + output + "</td></tr></table>");
}
</script>

<style>



/* attachments */
.fmgSectionH1 {

  font-weight: bold;
}
#fmgAttach {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
}

</style>
```